# naming the sequences

Tags: python, naming

I have a program for creating a fasta file of sequencesthrough itertools.

```
import itertools
input=['ARIMALTHNAEYSDSFTAL','ARIMFLTHNFEYSESFTAL','AHIMNPTENAEYHESFTAL','AHIMNPTENTEYWDSFTAL','AHIMNDTHNFEYHDSFTAL','AHIMNDTNNTEYWESFTAL','ARIMFDTENAEYHDSFTAL','AHIMADTNNTEYWDSFTAL','ARIMFLTENTEYHESFTAL']

l=len(input[0])

my_residues=[set() for _ in xrange(l)]
for h in input: 
    for i,x in enumerate(h): 
        my_residues[i].add(x)

my_residues=[list(x) for x in my_residues]
fo=open('autotest.fasta','w')
vals=[]
for x in itertools.product(*my_residues): 
    val = ''.join(x)
    vals.append('>'+'\n'+val)
    print val

with open('autotest.fasta','w') as fo:
    fo.write('\n'.join(vals))
fo.close()
```

This program is working perfectly.This will give output file called autotest.fasta which is looking like

```
>
AHIMAPTHNAEYHESFTAL
>
AHIMAPTHNAEYHDSFTAL
>
AHIMAPTHNAEYSESFTAL
>
AHIMAPTHNAEYSDSFTAL
>
AHIMAPTHNAEYWESFTAL
>
AHIMAPTHNAEYWDSFTAL
...
```

Here what I want is to name the sequence, so that output autotest.fasta will look like

```
>00
AHIMAPTHNAEYHESFTAL
>01
AHIMAPTHNAEYHDSFTAL
>02
AHIMAPTHNAEYSESFTAL
>03
AHIMAPTHNAEYSDSFTAL
>04
AHIMAPTHNAEYWESFTAL
>05
AHIMAPTHNAEYWDSFTAL
...
```

So that it can be applied to any input.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it is time you started upvoting useful solutions and accepting answers that you actually used

Answer (score 2):

```
vals=[]
counter=0
for x in itertools.product(*my_residues): 
    val = ''.join(x)
    vals.append('>%02d\n%s' % (counter, val))
    print val
    counter += 1
```